# What is the best way to send payment information to the server?

Tags: apache, react-native, ssl, django-rest-framework

I have made an application with React native and the application consumes information from an api made with django rest framework.
while working with this I had a concern on how to transfer card information from the application to the api. 
I configured the server to use ssl certificates, but i feel this is not enough.

**My question is, what and how are the best and safe ways to pass card information from my app to the server?**

I appreciate experiences and knowledge

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to not send card information to your server. Instead use one of the modern payment provides:

- [Stripe](https://stripe.com)
- [BrainTree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/nz)

etc (there are quite a few services that work this way)

All of these providers work a little differently to how you were thinking of taking payments:

1. What you do is in your frontend you send the user's card-details directly to them (Stripe or braintree etc)
2. they then store these securely and return to your frontend a random ID.
3. You can then send that to your backend (and store it)
4. to charge the card you hit their api asking them to charge the stored card for the ID.

This way your server never has the users card details.

If processing payments is not part of your core business, it is advised not to attempt store or process the card numbers yourself. The rules on security around handling card details are extremely complex. An example of this is the PSD2 of the European Union (for an easy to digest piece on one of the obligations, read [this](https://stripe.com/en-be/guides/strong-customer-authentication))

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it